# ruby on rails and android: How does JWT really work here

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, android-studio, authentication, jwt

ruby version 2.2.4
rails version 5.0.0.1

Hello People,

I am just a beginner in programming and I have the task to create an android app with Android Studio, where you can login and logout as a user. Therefore I need to use JSON API of the authentication of a rails server.

I followed a Token-based authentication tutorial with Ruby on Rails 5 API (http://tutorials.pluralsight.com/ruby-ruby-on-rails/token-based-authentication-with-ruby-on-rails-5-api). This tutorial shows how I get a token with JWT after using curl to post the credentials. After putting the right credentials in curl like this

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"email":"example@mail.com","password":"123123123"}' http://localhost:3000/authenticate
```

I finally receive the following token: `{"auth_token":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoxLCJleHAiOjE0NjA2NTgxODZ9.xsSwcPC22IR71OBv6bU_OGCSyfE89DvEzWfDU0iybMA"}`

As a total newbie I dont know what the next step is. What's about this token? How can this help me, to implement a login function in android app? How would this look like?

Answer (score 0):

this token may be needed for every request you make to the API. You should put it as header in every API request you make. Also, this may serve as indication of your session.

Comment: Ok but I still dont get it how this all is connected together. I have my android app with a login button. The user clicks on it and gives email and password which he registrated on rails server before. How can the android-program know if email and password are correct? How can android-program and rails server connect? I have a Msql database in ruby on rails. There are the emails and passwords saved i think. But what role does this token play? is it saved somewhere else? Very hard to grasp for me..

Answer (score 0):

Probably you will need the token to validate every request to the server.
Currently I'm using Retrofit to do the request and [okhttp](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Interceptors) to rewrite the header in the interceptor or the Authenticator API.
Also you have to take a look at the [Account Manager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html) documentation that should be helpful, because you probably have to refresh the token associated to an account.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. You said I need the token to validate every request to the server. So my understanding goes this way:                     I program a method on android, which invokes curl with the credentials from the user (email, password). Then a token will be generated and the program on android invokes a second curl command with the token inside the command, so that the user can be authorized. Am I thinking right?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with curl, but as far as I know the flow is the same:
- Get the user credentials (email and password)
- Post request to retrieve the token
- Check the server response (status code 200 if it's correct)
- Create new account with Account Manages with the email and the authorization code (not the password).
- And then in each header request you have to add the token (with an interceptor for example).
The Account Manager also helps you to refresh the token.

Comment: Ok but I just need to login and logout with my android app, the registration occurs on the ruby server: http://localhost:3000/users/sign_up. So do I need still the Account Manager?

Comment: You don't need it, but it helps you. I have not been in your situation, but if you store in the Account Manager the user and the token (you can store more data), when you want to logout the user, you just have to remove the token, I think.
One of the benefits of the token is that it is stateless, so keep in mind that you don't need to keep a session stored.

Comment: I followed a tutorial ( https://www.sitepoint.com/retrofit-a-simple-http-client-for-android-and-java/ ) which uses Retrofit for authentication with a php server. I want to implement this for my RoR server. Nevertheless I tried this out.  It can communicate with my ruby on rails server. If I login on android app with the right credentials, I see on the cmd line that it will be accepted. But I dont get something back. As I said I use JWT in RoR which gives a long token back. Is there a possibility that Retrofit can interpret this token? Or do I need to install JSON Web Token for Android?